# Ошибка при использовании --watch. LoadError: cannot load such file

Tags: debian, sass, scss

Когда команда выполняется, файл SCSS обновляется, но вместе с ошибкой перекомпиляция файла не происходит при изменении файла. Что можно попробовать?
[image: Скрин]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при использовании --watch. LoadError: cannot load such file](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1188387/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-watch-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса